# IAM Policy simulator - unexpected denied ListAllBuckets for s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Why is the `ListAllMyBuckets`policy denied? I use an explicit allow and the policy looks like this (ofc somebucketname is not the real name):

```
{
"Version":"2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::<somebucketname>",
            "arn:aws:s3:::<somebucketname>/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The policy simulator writes about `ListAllMyBuckets` if you expand the action listed in `Action Settings and Results`:

> This action **does not support** resource-level permissions. Policies granting access **must specify** "*" in the resource element.

Thus, your policy should use  `"Resource": "*"`:

```
{
    "Version":"2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<somebucketname>",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<somebucketname>/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```